# Drillthrough Performance Issue in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have a report which shows data as follows,

Source         Count
Internal       **200**
External       **300**
Miscellaneous  **100**

The expression for source is as follows "case when Source is null then 'Miscellaneous' else Source end"
The drill through is made on the 'count column' values.

So, when we click the count column corresponding to each source, the drillthrough keeps on running.
In the drillthrough, I have written the filter as "case when Source is null then 'Miscellaneous' else Source end" is prompted.

When I include the above filter the report runs for a long time.
When I exclude that, I get the drillthrough in seconds but the count doesn't match as the data is not filtered.
Any feedback on how to optimize?

Comment: Have you looked at the log files? Without analysis you can't really make any assumption.

Comment: Only that filter is causing the issue. Other than that everything is fine with the report. I tried passing the filter from another report to drillthrough and it is working fine now.